# How do I rename a Java .class file?

Tags: java, android, decompiling

I am debugging a program that uses a precompiled jar. I want to log calls made to a function in some class. The idea is to rename the original class file Xxx.class to Xxx0.class and define the original class name as:

```
class Xxx extends Xxx0 {
    void func() {
        Log.d(...);
        super.func();
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

(I did try the decompiler: there are strange control structures in the decompiled code, the decompiler probably does not generate the correct code for this program.)

Comment: @Juvanis Looks like it's the decimal form of binary [1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+18446744073709551615), or well 2^64-1.

Comment: @Juvanis what I used to generate my username is irrelevant.

Comment: @Juvanis please stay on topic. While it is a clever username, stackoverflow is not for off topic discussions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just rename a class file, because not only is the name of the class is used to calculate the name of the class file when loading it, but the name of the class is also stored in the class file, and must match the requested class.

Therefore, if you want to rename a class, you need to do so in the source code and recompile.

Comment: Yep, but since there are decompilers, someone could implement a rename tool.

Comment: Certainly, but I get the feeling it's probably easier and less complex to use JPDA or something to instrument the function in the live VM instead. :)

Comment: Well, that's probably an exaggeration, but I'd like to make the point that it wouldn't be as simple as simply changing the name in the class file; you'd also have to change all references to it in the constant pool, for instance, and I don't know the rest of the class format well enough off hand to say if there are any other symbolic references that would need to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rename a class ant you do not have the source java file then do the following steps:
**i) First open the file in jd(java decompiler) and then save(Ctrl+S) the source file.

ii) Rename the java file(F2) and also the class name inside the java file.

iii)Compile again the java file(using any java compiler) to .class file.**

This will solve your issue.
Try this and let me know in case of any concern.

**Note:** If you are facing issues with java decomplier the please try with another version of JD.
[Please visit here to download latest JD](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui)

Comment: Unfortunately, for namely that class jd shows `// INTERNAL ERROR //`.

Comment: Have you opened the class file with JD? Is it showing the java codes?

Comment: no, it is showing `// INTERNAL ERROR //`. If it showed java code, there would be no problem.

Comment: Can you please try with another(updated) version of JD? I think this might be JD issue.

Answer (score 1):

I did rename the class file, but it was a long and boring story. In my case, this was an Android application, you may need to convert your classes to an Android application to repeat what I did :). The sequence was:

1. Decompile the apk with apktool. You get the subdirectory *yourApkName*/smali/*packageName*/ with the decompiled source of your class there.
2. Copy the class and its subclasses to a new file, e.g. *Stuff.smali* becomes *Xtuff.smali* and *Stuff$Useless.smali* becomes *Xtuff$Useless.smali*
3. open these new files in a text editor, I used gedit.
4. Replace all occurrences of the full class path there, e.g. Lfoo/bar/baz/qux/Stuff becomes Lfoo/bar/baz/qux/Xtuff; it is better to see each replacement you are doing, but most likely you will replace all of them (Note: you do replace strings like Lfoo/bar/baz/qux/Stuff$Data but do not replace strings like Lfoo/bar/baz/qux/StuffData)
5. Replace all (or not all) occurrences of the class name "Stuff" with "Xtuff"; in this case it is very likely that you will replace not all occurrences. At this step you need some understanding of what you are doing.
6. (Save the original apk and) rebuild the apk with apktool, use the -f flag: `apktool b -f AppName AppName.apk`
7. extract classes.dex from that new apk (obtained at step 6); I used the Midnight Commander, it shows zipped archives (including dex and jar) as directories
8. convert dex to jar: `~/Downloads/dex2jar-0.0.9.13/d2j-jar2dex.sh classes.jar`, you get classes-dex2jar.jar
9. extract the new (renamed) classes to an Eclipse project (Xtuff.class, Xtuff$Useless, etc.), derive classes from top-level renamed classes (`class Stuff extends Xtuff`), compile, you get the new Stuff.class. (If you can debug now, you may begin debugging and skip the following steps.)
10. copy classes-dex2jar.jar to classes-X.jar, add the class files obtained at step 9 (including nested classes) to classes-X.jar
11. convert classes-X.jar to classes.dex
12. place this new classes.dex to the original apk
13. sign the apk: `jarsigner -verbose -keystore ./my.keystore ./AppName.apk mykey`
14. remove the original application, install the modified apk.

It's evident that a dedicated tool would make this long sequence much easier to perform.

PS This method, of course, is not for production code.

PPS This is not a general case recipe: if your class contains, say, a static factory method, the required modifications become even more tricky.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to change the name of .class file because it is linked with(same as) public class of java. still if you changed the name of .class file then you need to change the name of the class as well else it causes error.

once it complied (.java to .class) it converts into the bytecode so if you changed the name of class file you are not able to change the byte code directly but you can canvert your .class file to .java again using decompiler(reflection), then change the public class name as your changed file name, build it again and use it.

You can get many decompilers available, which can convert the .class to .java easily and 80% same.

Comment: The Java compiler does not convert Java source into OS native code, it compiles it into JVM compatible bytecode. The JVM then translates the bytecode into native code on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Java class files should not be renamed at your own free will. When you do so, the class file you edited will never be usable again due to errors. This is because the class file's name corresponds to your java class name.

With that, all you need to do is using a .class viewer in eclipse, copy the java codes shown in the .class file. Make another .java file and rename the class name with the file name you want. Compile your .java file and locate the corresponding .class.

Now, you already have the .class renamed successfully.

However, there are drawbacks. Just make sure to reflect the changes to other classes affected.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a bytecode manipulation library like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) and change the name in the [class visitor](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor.html#visit%28int,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29).

*However, I'm not sure whether you may still need to update references to the type in other types even if you provide your own alternative - do synthetic accessors translate to subtypes?*

If the purpose is logging, there are less convoluted ways than replacing the type: instrumenting the method with [AOP](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/) or bytecode manipulation as above.

Answer (score -1):

This is a classic task for aspect-oriented programming. See, for example, [Aspect Oriented Android Development – Tool Integration](http://deansserver.co.uk/~dean/2011/07/18/aspect-oriented-android-development-tool-integration/).